# EXTJS boxcomponent not updated

Tags: extjs

In extjs, I wish to update a boxcomponent (inside a tab)with a json response data. the box is havign a tpl like this:

```
 this.someBox.tpl=new Ext.XTemplate(
'<table>',
'<tr><td width="110"><b>ID:</b></td><td> {Id}<br /></td></tr>',
'</table>'
);
```

This is the code to populate the box:

```
this.someTab.populateData=function(){   
DoAJAXAction({
url:"ajaxSupport.action",
isShowWaitDialog: 'true',
action: "getIDAction",
scope:this,
onSuccess:function(action,response){
var jsonResponse=Ext.util.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
this.someeBox.update(jsonResponse.rows);
}
});
```

DOAJAXAction is a custom function. The response is :

```
{"total":1,"rows":[{"Id":"134"}],"isSuccess":true,"isError":false,"errorMessage":null}
```

But still the ID is not populated in the box.
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the response is a jsonarray and not a jsonobject, we need to do :
this.someeBox.update(jsonResponse.rows[0]);